# How to scrape full article from the website - Python 3.6

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I would like to scrape the full text from this website: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2016/html/is161020.en.html. That is, from *"Ladies and gentlemen,..."* to the end *"...So you can see actually that the spread between loans to SMEs and loans to large corporates has declined quite considerably.*"

However, my code only scrapes until *"We are now at your disposal for questions"*  (middle of the text) .I really appreciate if you could help me to solve this issue.

Here is the code:

```
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import urllib
    import pandas as pd
    import ssl
    import os
    import time
    import string



# function loads html source code of given url
    ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
    user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.1.2 Safari/605.1.15'
    headers = {'User-Agent':user_agent,}
    url = "https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2016/html/is161020.en.html"
    req = urllib.request.Request(url, None, headers) 
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req) 
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    article = soup.find('article')
    paragraphs = article.find_all('p')
    print(article)
```

Comment: Visit the documentation at https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ and search for `Another common task is extracting all the text from a page`

Comment: What do you mean by "only scrapes until"? What's the output of your code? You have a `print(article)` at the end. Is that what you mean?

Comment: @HåkenLid Hi Håken, the output of my code is the text starting from "Ladies and gentlemen" and ending at "We are now at your disposal for questions." (middle of the text). I would like to have a complete text

Comment: Is that the output from `print(article)` ?

Comment: Yes, it is the output from my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the complete text is in paragraphs:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
resp = requests.get('https://www.ecb.europa.eu/press/pressconf/2016/html/is161020.en.html')
soup = BeautifulSoup(resp.content, 'html5lib')
article = soup.find('article')
paragraphs = article.find_all('p')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, @API. I tried with  your code, but it also extracts paragraphs outside the full text. For example, the first paragraph is 'We are always working to improve this website for our users. To do this, we use the anonymous data provided by cookies.\nLearn more about how we use cookies' :(

Comment: can you check it now with the `html5lib` parser?

Comment: Its' awesome. Your code works like a charm. Thank you very much for your time, .@API